# mysql - how to select a string in column?

Tags: mysql

I have column contain a string like that :

"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R3-kfnKmDVc"

I want to select this column but get string like that "R3-kfnKmDVc".
How do?

Comment: Can you provide more information about how you identify this string?

Comment: Are parameters possible after the id ?

Answer (score 4):

If you want the part of the string after the last `=`, you can do:

```
select substring_index(col, '=', -1)
```

In the event that the string may not contain an `'='`:

```
select (case when col like '%=%' then substring_index(col, '=', -1) end)
```

Answer (score 0):

By getting the id only you are not improving the performance, so you can simply fetch it from DB then use regex functions to get the id of the youtube link.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

SELECT SUBSTRING('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R3-kfnKmDVc', (SELECT LOCATE('?v=', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R3-kfnKmDVc') + 3));

-> usage in select:

select SUBSTRING(url_name, LOCATE('?v=', url_name) + 3) from table;

Thank You